# how can i test to see if only one of the methods works in xcode with swift programming?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, func

I do not want to run the whole project as i have other classes and also the main storyboard runs which i dont want, i just want to run the below code, is this possible?

```
import Foundation


var eventCapacity : Int?;
var eventAttendees : String?;

var attendees = 0;


func addAttendee (user_id:User){

    if eventCapacity < attendees {
        attendees++;
        print("Going to event")
    }
}


func removeAttendee(user_id:User){

        attendees--;
        print("Not going")
}


func getAttendees(){

    print(attendees)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vishnu gondlekar says: Use `playgrounds`!

But one small side note:

> For testing small pieces of code we usually write **Unit Tests** ;-)
>   And as default every new Xcode projects comes with a test setup ... so
>   go ahead and write tests! At the same time you will improve the quality of your code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Playground` to achieve that. Open Xcode and then go to File -> New -> Playground and follow the steps. Copy your code there along with the implementation of User class. And you should be able to call your functions and test them.